# Conduct AngleAxisToRotationMatirx on part of a double arrray in Ceres?

Tags: eigen3, ceres-solver

Nowadays I'm working with Ceres and Eigen. And I have a **6x3 = 18**-d double array, let's call it **xs**, which is defined as:

```
double xs[6*3];
```

Basically **xs** contains the 6 rotations expressed in angle-axis format. And I need to turn each rotation of all 6 into rotation matrix format, then matrix multiplication will be conducted.

```
struct F1 {
    template <typename T> bool operator()(const T* const xs,
                                    T* residual) const {
    Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<T,3,1> > m0(xs, 3);

    T m[9], res[3];
    ceres::AngleAxisToRotationMatrix(m0, m);


    residual[0] = res[0];
    residual[1] = res[1];
    residual[2] = res[2];
}
```

Here in the example code I extract first 3 elements of **xs** via **Eigen::Map**, then I applied **AngleAxisToRotationMatrix** on it. But I keep receiving such errors:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘AngleAxisToRotationMatrix(Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<ceres::Jet<double, 18>, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >&, ceres::Jet<double, 1> [9])’
```

Can somebody lend me a hand here? I'm pretty new to Ceres and Eigen, it really drove me almost to crazy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ceres::AngleAxisToRotationMatrix` expects raw pointers:

```
AngleAxisToRotationMatrix(xs, m);
```

Comment: Yeah, I see. But the issue is, xs is an array of 18 elements, while AngleAxisToRotationMatrix requires a pointer of 3 elements. That's where the trouble comes from.

Comment: that does not matter, it will access the 3 first elements only.

Comment: And can I ask you another question? Now I have the same xs, a 6*3 = 18-d double array. I want to construct 6 Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T,3,1>> object from this array (xs), one for every 3 elements of xs. I tried using std::vector to hold them, then construct them one by one dynamically. But failed. Do you know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Better see them as a 3x6 `Eigen::Matrix<double,3,6>` using Map, and call `.col(i)` to access the i-th.